# Is there a tool to publish sourcecode as html for vb.net and c#?

Tags: publish

A customer want's to view the source code of a project that we are building for them. I'd like to publish the code just like the way that Microsoft is publishing their reference sources (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Is there a tool that I can use to create the html code from vb.net and c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally never used it but my co-worker has, you can use SandCastle to generate web-based documentation about your project that looks and acts exactly like referencesource.

[SandCastle on Codeplex](https://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this.